Comma separated names list to parse into dictionary
I'd like to parse a list of assignees into a dictionary field. Creating the dictionary is not a problem since Python re.match() returned value can be grouped into dictionary fields re.match().groupdict().
My regex r'assignees:((\s\w+){2}[\s|,])+' matches as expected with the following example input if I test it in this website:
Input:
assignees: Peter Jones, Michael Jackson, Tim Burton
However, the same regex pattern in Python only matches Peter Jones, resulting in:
assignees: Peter Jones,
My pattern is declared in a variable p in this way:
p = re.compile(r'assignees:(?P<assignees>((\s\w+){2}[\s|,])+')

The final output I'm aiming for is:
{'assignees': 'Peter Jones, Michael Jackson, Tim Burton'}

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong/missing here please?

See [mcve].....

Cool! I'll include a MRE next time to give more info to my question.

Why are you using re for this?

It's the most effective approach to parse my text into a dictionary with Python builtin methods instead of using packages. I heard that learning you language well could be more valuable than relying on external packages only. Sure, there are use cases that demonstrate that built-ins might no be the best approach.

Your pattern was missing a parentheses and the question has no MRE, but this gives the result I believe you want.  If it isn't satisfactory, make a MRE next time:
import re

s = 'assignees: Peter Jones, Michael Jackson, Tim Burton'
p = re.compile(r'assignees:\s*(?P<assignees>([^,]+(?:,[^,]+)*))')
m = p.match(s)
print(m.groupdict())

Output:
{'assignees': 'Peter Jones, Michael Jackson, Tim Burton'}


Oh, I see you changed the pattern. That's fine, I just need a couple of minutes to understand it before checking this as the right answer

I think I get it. Your regex focuses on matching commas instead of words and commas to make sure that someone with two names for instances still matches the pattern. I'm asking to make sure that I understand the answering instead of copying, pasting it and then move on.

@wavesinaroom yes, it captures a no-comma item, optionally followed by zero or more comma plus another item

Awesome! I was fixated on the idea of matching two sets of words and a comma than it never occurred to me to focus on commas. I learned something new today, thanks again Mark!

@wavesinaroom Since you aren't parsing the names from the commas (yet) you could just do r'assignees:\s*(.*)$' to capture everything after the label to the end of the line as well. I assume that you may have a larger text that contains this sample string...

Alright I'll try that as well. My idea is to parse that match into a list after getting the dictionary from my match result. I feel like you can get matches in multiple ways with regex. I'm still a beginner and maybe there are one solution cases but I'll know that with more experience writing my patterns.
